# With webpack how do you detect a code splitting error?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Using webpack with [code splitting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) is it possible to detect when a chunk doesn't download due to a network error or an improperly configured output path (i.e. the additional bundles are where you told webpack it is). The `require.ensure` [documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/api-in-modules.html#require-ensure) makes it look like it is not possible to be notified when a chunk fails to download. Am I forced to add some sort of manual timeout that checks to see if the `require.ensure` callback was called?

Here's the function definition of `require.ensure`:

```
require.ensure(dependencies: String[], callback: function([require]), [chunkName: String])
```